# How do I create a struct of references to traits when one object might implement multiple of the traits?

Tags: rust, mutability, borrowing

I have a struct which manages several sensors. I have a gyroscope, accelerometer, magnetometer, barometer, and thermometer. All of which are traits.

```
pub struct SensorManager {
    barometer: Barometer + Sized,
    thermometer: Thermometer + Sized,
    gyroscope: Gyroscope + Sized,
    accelerometer: Accelerometer + Sized,
    magnetometer: Magnetometer + Sized
}
```

I need to make it modular so in the configuration file you can specify which sensors you are using.

The problem is that some of the sensors overlap. For example: one person can have an LSM9DS0 which contains gyroscope, accelerometer, and magnetometer while another person can have an L3GD20 gyroscope and an LSM303D accelerometer, magnetometer.

In C++ I would store pointers or references, but I am not sure how to properly implement this safely in Rust.

Short version: Need to have references to each sensor as members of this struct. Some of these references are of the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C++ I would store pointers or references

Rust isn't that alien. You do the same thing. The main difference is that Rust prevents you from being able to mutate one thing via two different paths or to have a reference that dangles.

Answering your question has **many** potential solutions. For example, you don't describe whether you need to be able to mutate the sensors or describe if the sensors will outlive the manager, if threads will be involved, etc.. All of these things affect how micro-optimized the code can be.

The maximally-flexible solution is to:

1. use [*shared ownership*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html), such as that provided by [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) or [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html). This allows multiple things to own the sensor.
2. use [*interior mutability*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html), such as that provided by [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) or [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html). This moves enforcement of a single mutating reference at a time from compile time to run time.
3. use [*trait objects*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) to model dynamic dispatch since the decision of what concrete objects to use is made at run time.

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

trait Barometer {
    fn get(&self) -> i32;
    fn set(&self, value: i32);
}

trait Thermometer {
    fn get(&self) -> i32;
    fn set(&self, value: i32);
}

trait Gyroscope {
    fn get(&self) -> i32;
    fn set(&self, value: i32);
}

struct Multitudes;
impl Barometer for Multitudes {
    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        1
    }
    fn set(&self, value: i32) {
        println!("Multitudes barometer set to {}", value)
    }
}

impl Thermometer for Multitudes {
    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        2
    }
    fn set(&self, value: i32) {
        println!("Multitudes thermometer set to {}", value)
    }
}

struct AutoGyro;

impl Gyroscope for AutoGyro {
    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        3
    }
    fn set(&self, value: i32) {
        println!("AutoGyro gyroscope set to {}", value)
    }
}

struct SensorManager {
    barometer: Rc<RefCell<dyn Barometer>>,
    thermometer: Rc<RefCell<dyn Thermometer>>,
    gyroscope: Rc<RefCell<dyn Gyroscope>>,
}

impl SensorManager {
    fn new(
        barometer: Rc<RefCell<dyn Barometer>>,
        thermometer: Rc<RefCell<dyn Thermometer>>,
        gyroscope: Rc<RefCell<dyn Gyroscope>>,
    ) -> Self {
        Self {
            barometer,
            thermometer,
            gyroscope,
        }
    }

    fn dump_info(&self) {
        let barometer = self.barometer.borrow();
        let thermometer = self.thermometer.borrow();
        let gyroscope = self.gyroscope.borrow();

        println!(
            "{}, {}, {}",
            barometer.get(),
            thermometer.get(),
            gyroscope.get()
        );
    }

    fn update(&self) {
        self.barometer.borrow_mut().set(42);
        self.thermometer.borrow_mut().set(42);
        self.gyroscope.borrow_mut().set(42);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let multi = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Multitudes));
    let gyro = Rc::new(RefCell::new(AutoGyro));

    let manager = SensorManager::new(multi.clone(), multi, gyro);

    manager.dump_info();
    manager.update();
}
```

[Complete example on the Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db1a7f4b3815fa9124306ecfc31590e3)

---

> ```
> barometer: Barometer + Sized,
> ```

You really don't want to to this. `Barometer` is both a **trait** and a **type**, but the type doesn't have a size. it always needs to be referenced behind a pointer (`&Barometer`, `Box<Barometer>`, `RefCell<Barometer>`, etc.)

See also:

- [What does "dyn" mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/155423)