# Why do fat pointers sometimes percolate outwards?

Tags: rust

I thought that I had understood fat pointers in Rust, but I have a case where I can't understand why they seem to percolate outwards from an inner type. Presumably my mental model is off, but I'm struggling to come up with a satisfactory explanation for this code:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::mem::size_of;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", size_of::<Rc<RefCell<Vec<u8>>>>());
    println!("{}", size_of::<Rc<RefCell<Debug>>>());
    println!("{}", size_of::<Box<Rc<RefCell<Debug>>>>());
}
```

which, on a 64-bit machine, prints `8, 16, 8`. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c7eb26309ea99a8d1a3171771a4f1908).

Since `Rc` makes a `Box` internally (using `into_raw_non_null`), I expected this to print `8, 8, 8`. Is there a reason why, at least from `size_of`'s perspective, the fat pointer seems to percolate outwards from `Debug`, even past `Rc`'s `Box`? Is it because it's stored as a raw pointer perhaps?

Comment: You are encourage to use [the `dyn` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650070/what-does-dyn-mean-in-a-type) to be clear that you are using a trait object.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately, `Rc<RefCell<Debug>>` *is* the trait object and trait objects are fat pointers. The types inside and outside of it are not fat pointers.

---

There are no fat pointers in the `Vec<u8>` set, whatsoever. A `Vec<T>` is a `(*mut T, usize, usize)`, a `RefCell<T>` is a `(T, usize)`, and an `Rc<T>` is a `(*mut T)`.

```
size_of              | is
---------------------+---
           Vec<u8>   | 24
   RefCell<Vec<u8>>  | 32
Rc<RefCell<Vec<u8>>> |  8
```

Your second and third cases do involve a fat pointer for a trait object: `Rc<RefCell<dyn Debug>>`. Putting a trait object behind *another* pointer (the `Rc`) creates a **thin pointer** to the concrete type: `*mut RefCell<dyn Debug>`.

```
size_of                     | is
----------------------------+---
    Rc<RefCell<dyn Debug>>  | 16
Box<Rc<RefCell<dyn Debug>>> |  8
```

Notably, it's impossible to create a `RefCell<dyn Debug>`:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn std::fmt::Debug` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:4:20
  |
4 |     println!("{}", mem::size_of::<RefCell<dyn Debug>>());
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: within `std::cell::RefCell<dyn std::fmt::Debug>`, the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `dyn std::fmt::Debug`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: required because it appears within the type `std::cell::RefCell<dyn std::fmt::Debug>`
  = note: required by `std::mem::size_of`
```

The trait object requires some indirection; when you add some, you've finally constructed some type of fat pointer.

---

You can use the unstable option `-Z print-type-sizes` to explore the layout of structs:

```
type: `std::rc::RcBox<std::cell::RefCell<dyn std::fmt::Debug>>`: 24 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    field `.strong`: 8 bytes
    field `.weak`: 8 bytes
    field `.value`: 8 bytes

type: `core::nonzero::NonZero<*const std::rc::RcBox<std::cell::RefCell<dyn std::fmt::Debug>>>`: 16 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    field `.0`: 16 bytes

type: `std::ptr::NonNull<std::rc::RcBox<std::cell::RefCell<dyn std::fmt::Debug>>>`: 16 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    field `.pointer`: 16 bytes

type: `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<dyn std::fmt::Debug>>`: 16 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    field `.ptr`: 16 bytes
    field `.phantom`: 0 bytes, offset: 0 bytes, alignment: 1 bytes

type: `std::cell::RefCell<dyn std::fmt::Debug>`: 8 bytes, alignment: 8 bytes
    field `.borrow`: 8 bytes
    field `.value`: 0 bytes
```

I'm not 100% about parsing this output, as I expect `RefCell<dyn Debug>` to be an unsized type (as shown by the error above). I assume the meaning of "0 bytes" is overloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, which was very interesting. I also struggled a bit to interpret all of `-Z print-type-sizes`. I think I've now realised that the key to my original question is that the `RefCell` is storing a fat pointer, so when `Box::into_raw` is used in `Rc`, the fat pointer is passed through (so to speak).