# How to define a generic type conversion for converting any error to a standard error type?

Tags: rust

I want to convert any error returned from another crate to my own error type so that I can return any error in a `Result<X, CalendarError>`.

I am trying something like the following

```
use std::error::Error;

struct CalendarError {
    msg: String,
}

impl<Err> From<std::convert::From<Err>> for CalendarError
where
    Err: Error,
{
    fn from(err: Err) -> Self {
        CalendarError {
            msg: format!("error: {}", err),
        }
    }
}
```

I get compile errors:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::convert::From<Err> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:7:11
  |
7 | impl<Err> From<std::convert::From<Err>> for CalendarError
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::convert::From<Err> + 'static)`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>

error[E0038]: the trait `std::convert::From` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/lib.rs:7:11
  |
7 | impl<Err> From<std::convert::From<Err>> for CalendarError
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
```

How do I fix this?

*Edit: I have got it to compile (as advised in the referenced post) by removing the `From` definition, adding the following:*

```
impl CalendarError {
    fn from_error<Err>(err: Err) -> Self
    where
        Err: Error,
    {
        CalendarError {
            msg: format!("error: {}", err),
        }
    }
}
```

*and then adding the call to `map_err` to do the conversion explicitly:*

```
let u = from_reader(reader).map_err(CalendarError::from_error)?;
```

Comment: Your immediate problem is that you've put `From` twice, once as a trait and once as a type (see also [What does “dyn” mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/155423)). You want just `impl<Err> From<Err> for CalendarError where Err: Error`. However, [once you do that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b0a6a9e4e42adcd42b0ece979dac0362), you'll run into the linked duplicate

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, I followed the linked answers and I have updated the question with my changes to my program.