# Returning an iterator from function in Rust returns "size ... cannot be known at compile time"

Tags: rust

I'm trying to return an iterator from this function which does some filtering on a map.

I have tried:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;


struct Foo {
    my_map: HashMap<String, String>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> dyn Iterator<Item = String> {
            self.my_map
                .values()
                .into_iter()
                .filter(|m| m.len() == 0)
                .collect()
    }
}
```

This however returns

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn Iterator<Item = String> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
```

After some search online with some suggestions to use a `Box`, I got to this

```
use std::collections::HashMap;


struct Foo {
    my_map: HashMap<String, String>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>> {
        Box::new(
            self.my_map
                .values()
                .into_iter()
                .filter(|m| m.len() == 0)
                .collect(),
        )
    }
}
```

Which failed since it couldn't infer the type of `Box`.

After trying to add an explicit type arg :

```
use std::collections::HashMap;


struct Foo {
    my_map: HashMap<String, String>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>> {
        Box::<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>::new(
            self.my_map
                .values()
                .into_iter()
                .filter(|m| m.len() == 0)
                .collect(),
        )
    }
}
```

It now fails with:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `new` found for struct `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>` in the current scope
    --> src/lib.rs:10:45
     |
10   |           Box::<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>::new(
     |                                               ^^^ function or associated item not found in `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>`
     |
     = note: the method `new` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
             `dyn Iterator<Item = String>: Sized`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=38cc2bd6a203334304f22dc19c53e19e)

I'm very new to the language so not exactly sure what's going on here. How can I return the iterator in this case?

Comment: You were very close in your first snippet - you just need to change `dyn` to `impl`, change `Item = String` to `Item = &String`, and remove `.collect`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=254788ed81aef324dfe85bd587466e00.

Comment: Related: [What does “dyn” mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/9716597)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/what-is-the-correct-way-to-return-an-iterator-or-any-other-trait) (Sorry for the bombardment of comments!)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I will read through those thanks for sharing. I even tried the `impl` approach but I completely missed the `.collect` part