# Is dyn Trait a reference type?

Tags: rust, traits

In Rust a reference is effectively a raw pointer with constraints on how it can be used, just as references are in C++.

```
type T = i64;
let my_variable: &T;
```

In C++, unlike a raw pointer, a reference cannot be `nullptr` (point to address `0`) and it must be initialized when it is created. Broadly speaking, it is the same in Rust.

In Rust, a `Box` type is effectively a smart pointer, analogous to C++ `std::unique_ptr`.

**On the subject of traits, for which there is no direct analogy in C++:**

We can pass a trait object to a function using a explicit reference.

```
trait Trait;

fn func(arg: &dyn Trait);
```

However, the following does not compile:

```
trait Trait;

fn func(arg: dyn Trait);
```

This is the reason:

```
arg: doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

It seem that `dyn Trait` is not actually a fat pointer itself, but that the "reference" version `&dyn Trait` is?

Box-ing the trait does compile...

```
fn func(arg: Box<dyn Trait>)
```

The question is why? I'm not totally sure this question is particularly meaningful. It seems that Box is treated by the Rust compiler in a somewhat special way, anyway.

I would have expected to see this instead:

```
fn func(arg: Box<&dyn Trait>)
```

And in fact, this seems to compile also.

So - what would the difference between these two cases be?

- `Box<dyn Trait>`
- `Box<&dyn Trait>`

and

- `dyn Trait`  - (not a meaningful concept)?
- `&dyn Trait`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "dyn" mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650070/what-does-dyn-mean-in-a-type) and links therein.

Comment: To draw a C++ analogy, the behavior of `dyn T` is essentially (exactly?) the same as abstract types in C++. If `T` is an abstract type, you can't pass a `T` to a function, by you can pass a `T*` or `T&` or `std::unique_ptr<T>`. An abstract type is just an opaque front to some actual non-abstract type, which may have any size but which provides some consistent interface that the abstract type describes (e.g., certain vtable entries)

Comment: @Brian61354270 It's quite different from C++ though because in C++ abstract functions are implemented as part of the type, whereas in Rust behavior and data are more distinctly separated. Traits can be written without any type, whereas in C++ even an Abstract class (interface) has a type.

Comment: It's only different in how the languages describe them. C++'s ABCs and Rust's trait objects are just the "language level frontends" for the idea of having arbitrary runtime objects with consistent vtables.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Well, if you go all the way to machine code you can argue that all languages are the same... assuming they are Turing complete I suppose... They really are not the same at all conceptually though. You cannot implement an abstract interface for `float` in C++. You can implement a trait for `f32` in Rust. The fact they (functions and data) are conceptually segregated, which is really much more meaningful than bonding behaviors to types (C++ classes), means they really are quite different.

Answer (score 1):

The `dyn Trait` type is an unsized type. This means that we cannot know the size of a value of type `dyn Trait` at compile time. In Rust, the type of any variable cannot be an unsized type.

However, regardless of whether `T: Sized` (that is, regardless of whether type `T` has a known size), the types `&T`, `Box<T>`, `*mut T`, etc. are all sized. A pointer to an unsized value will contain extra information about the value itself. In particular, a pointer to `dyn Trait` will contain a pointer to the underlying value, plus a pointer to the vtable for the value's trait implementation. Such a pointer is called a "fat pointer".

> It seem that dyn Trait is not actually a fat pointer itself, but that the "reference" version &dyn Trait is

This is exactly right, except that `&dyn Trait` is a type in its own right, just like `&i32` is a different type than `i32` is. Calling it "the 'reference' version" is thus slightly inaccurate.

A `Box<&dyn Trait>` is a Box which holds a `&dyn Trait` inside it. Thus, there are two levels of indirection going on.

By contrast, a `Box<dyn Trait>` holds a `dyn Trait` inside it. That is, a `Box<dyn Trait>` consists of a pointer to a heap-allocated value of some unknown type `T`, where `T: Trait`, together with a pointer to the v-table for `T`'s implementation of `Trait`.

Finally, you should generally not use `dyn Trait` to make a function polymorphic. `dyn Trait` is typically used to make containers able to hold any item that that implements `Trait`. Instead of

```rust
fn func(arg: Box<dyn Trait>)
```

you should write

```rust
fn func(arg: impl Trait)
```

or, equivalently,

```rust
fn func<T: Trait>(arg: T)
```

The latter declarations will implement `func` using static, rather than dynamic, polymorphism.

Comment: On the latter point - what I was trying to build requires dynamic polymorphism, in this case related to return values, which need to be a dynamically dispatched return type, contained inside a Box. Does that explain why I went with this approach or do you still think that taking the static compiled approach is the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

`impl Trait` is more akin to a concept template constraint, and thus **static (or compile-time) polymorphism**.

`dyn Trait` could be assimilated to the way a `Trait*` or `Trait&` work in the sense that they can both hold an instance to an implementation of `T` instead of just `Trait` which in C++ could be viewed as an abstract class with only pure virtual functions. And as such, it's used mainly for **dynamic (or runtime) polymorphism**.

Although you need a `Box<dyn Trait>` (instead of just `dyn Trait`) because Rust only wants same size objects on non-template / non-generics functions (1 layout for 1 function, vs N layouts for N functions). That's because `Box` is more or less a pointer, so the size is the same for any type.

It's for the same reasons you'd use `Trait*` instead of `Trait` in C++:

- If the type is abstract, you can't have instances of it
- You'd be truncating the object

You also noticed you can use `&dyn Trait` which would be the equivalent of a `Trait&` in C++.

Comment: I don't really see the concept analogy. The point of `dyn X` is that we don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: `std::integral auto x` is the same, you accept anything that satisfies `std::integral` but don't really know it's type since you're using auto. You can't have an instance of a concept like you can't have an instance of a trait. You can have an instance of some type that satisfies a concept, or of some struct that implements that trait.

Comment: I think you're thinking along the lines of generics / `impl Trait` instead of `dyn Trait`. It's a bit muddled since Rust uses traits for both its static and dynamic dispatch features, but this question is about the dynamic dispatch use case. With `std::integral auto x`, you're constraining the static type of `x`, but it's still something that is fully known and substituted at compile time (just ask `decltype`). `dyn Trait` is something very different, since it models a type that isn't known at compile time and which may end up being anything of any size at runtime.

Comment: I see, I'll update my answer

Comment: "That's because `Box` is more or less a pointer, so the size is the same for any type." Incorrect. A `Box<dyn Trait>` is twice as large as a normal pointer.

Comment: From the Rust docs: A pointer type that uniquely owns a heap allocation of type T